# Is there a way to always have vs.net run as administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

Every time I want to open up a solution in vs.net, I have to first click on the vs.net icon, run as admin, and then open and search for the solution in the file system.

i.e I can't just click on the solution file and fire things up because it won't open since I have to run as admin.

is there any easier way? (vs.net 2008)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the visual studio icon and choose "Properties".  There should be a "Compatibility" tab, and that tab should have a checkbox option to "Run this program as Administrator".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a SuperUser question.  But right click on Devenv.exe -> Properties -> Compatibility Tab -> Privilege Level section, click "Run this program as an administrator".

Comment: Note that this option is grayed out when UAC is off.

Answer (score 0):

I turn off UAC. It may be big-headed of me, but I like to think I'm advanced enough as a user to not need the computer to protect me from myself.

Comment: its my host that is the issue.

Comment: @mrblah, you are doing development on your host machine?  Wouldn't it be easier (and far safer) to develop locally, and then deploy?

Comment: We don't install VS on the host.  I highly recommend you develop locally.

Comment: Turning of UAC for only running VS as administrator every time? UAC is not useless. I even expect windows command line to have something like "sudo" in next release.

Comment: that sudo like ability from command line could be RunAs and is has been there for a while

Answer (score 0):

I think you set run as admin in the program files tree on:

Launcher: VSLauncher.exe

and

IDE: devenv.exe

Answer (score 0):

To open Visual Studio / Rider always in admin mode for Windows 11, follow these steps:
[image]